# Unable to start anchor test

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

I am using `anchor` to run the solana test validator, so I tried with `anchor test` but got the error that its not able to start the validator. But when I run `solana-test-validator`, it's working. It's an error from anchor. Is there any way to correct the anchor boilerplate code?

Error:

```
Unable to start test validator. Check .anchor/test-ledger/test-ledger-log.txt for errors.
```

.anchor/test-ledger/test-ledger-log.txt contains

```
Ledger location: .anchor/test-ledger
Log: .anchor/test-ledger/validator.log
Initializing...
```

Comment: Please update the original question with what is in `test-ledger-log.txt` that could help us determine the error

Comment: @JacobCreech Please check. It can't initialize a validator.

Comment: What happens when you run validator in one tab and `anchor test` in another tab?